# A question about harmonic conjugate

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Show hat if $v(x,y)$ is harmonic conjugate of $u(x,y)$ in a domain $D$. Then every harmonic conjugate of $u(x,y)$ must be of form $v(x,y)+a$ where a is real constant

*My idea:*

since $v$ is harmonic conjugate of $u$ then it satisfies C-R equation

then $u_x=v_y,v_x=-u_y$ so result comes from this equation is i am right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. It follows from your observation that if you have two harmonic conjugates of the same function, then they have the same partial derivatives with respect to both variables. Therefore, their difference is constant (and real, of course, since we are dealing with real functions here).

Comment: i need little proof idea actuvally i am trying but not get it

Comment: @rajendra Suppose that both $v$ and $w$ are both harmonic conjugates of $u$. Then it follows from the Cauchy-Riemann equations that $v_x=w_x$ and that $v_y=w_w$. In other words, $(v-w)_x=(v-w)_y\equiv0$. Therefore, the function $v-w$ is constant, that is, there is a $a\in\mathbb R$ such that $v-w\equiv a$. In other words, $v=w+a$.